# Internet Explorer redirect to paypal not working

Tags: html, internet-explorer, paypal

I have a client site which the redirect to paypal is not working in IE.

I have googled this and found various 'solutions' and applied them sadly none of them work.  The site does not use frames and switching on IE7 compatibility does nothing either.

We are using the paypal.class.php written by Micah Carrick and everything works in all other browsers except IE where we just get a "Please wait, your order is being processed..." message and no redirect to paypal.

I have noticed that the class creates a form which has a body and html tags and these get inserted into the main page, so realistically the html is malformed, but everything works fine in all browsers except IE?

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: What version of IE? All of them? Maybe you can send us a link of your site so we can take a look.

Answer (score 1):

IE is very strange actually and strict as well. 
In the `submit_form` function of the `paypal.class.php`, try submitting the form using a JavaScript function rather than using `onload` on the `body` tag.

For example,

**Rather than**

```
<body onLoad="document.form.submit">
<form id ="form" id="form_paypal"></form>
</body>
```

**Use**

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
function test(){document.getElementById('form_paypal').submit();}

window.onload=test;
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id ="form" id="form_paypal"></form>
</body>
```

I hope this will do for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the paypal form is nested in another form.

I had a similar problem, and I solved bringing the paypal form out from the other that was containing it.